# Trouble Installing Rails in cygwin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, gcc

```
I'm trying to figure Ruby on Rails in cygwin, and I;ve used the native cygwin installer, however I get this error message when I try
$ gem install rails. I've also tried another route with RailInstaller and but I don't think Cygwin can locate the correct path.
```

**//error message**
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing rails:
            ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
        /usr/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
        --with-atomic_reference-dir
        --without-atomic_reference-dir
        --with-atomic_reference-include
        --without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include
        --with-atomic_reference-lib
        --without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link0'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:712:in `try_run'
        from extconf.rb:26:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out
```

**//This is the makefile document, could it perhaps be because I don't have the right gcc?**

```
"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-cygwin -I/usr/include/ruby-1.\
9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.    -ggdb -O2 -pipe   -fno-stric\
t-aliasing  conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib -L.      -lruby191  -lpthread -lrt -ldl \
-lcrypt  "
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot\
 find -lcrypt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */


**Thanks a bunch!**
```

Comment: It says it cannot find the crypt libraries. You probably need to install the dev version of crypt from the Cygwin installer.

Comment: Hi Casper, thanks for the help, I downloaded the crypt dev version but I still get the same cannot find -lcrypt error, any ideas?

Comment: Found the right crypt, still some errors, but I'll go through them one by one. Thanks!

Comment: Which crypt was the right crypt? I can see mcrypt and bcrypt on cygwin installer.

Answer (score 3):

`ld -lcrypt --verbose` *(the failing command is: `ld -lcrypt`)*

**demands for:** *(spanish for saying it didn't find anyhting there)*

```
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/libcrypt.dll.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/crypt.dll.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/libcrypt.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/crypt.lib
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/libcrypt.dll
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/crypt.dll
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/libcrypt.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/libcrypt.dll.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/crypt.dll.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/libcrypt.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/crypt.lib
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/libcrypt.dll
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/crypt.dll
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/libcrypt.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/w32api/libcrypt.dll.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/w32api/crypt.dll.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/w32api/libcrypt.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/w32api/crypt.lib
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/w32api/libcrypt.dll
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/w32api/crypt.dll
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/w32api/libcrypt.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/libcrypt.dll.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/crypt.dll.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/libcrypt.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/crypt.lib
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/libcrypt.dll
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/crypt.dll
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/crypt.lib
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/libcrypt.dll.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/crypt.dll.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/libcrypt.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/crypt.lib
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/libcrypt.dll
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/crypt.dll
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/crypt.lib
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/w32api/libcrypt.dll.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/w32api/crypt.dll.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/w32api/libcrypt.a
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/w32api/crypt.lib
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/w32api/libcrypt.dll
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/w32api/crypt.dll
    falló el intento de abrir /usr/lib/w32api/crypt.lib
    ld: no se puede encontrar -lcrypt
```

`$ find / -type f -name 'libcrypt*' 2>/dev/null`

*(`2>/dev/null` to get rid of permission error messages for the windows folders)*

**resulted in:** *(relevant lines)*

```
    /lib/w32api/libcrypt32.a
    /lib/w32api/libcryptdlg.a
    /lib/w32api/libcryptdll.a
    /lib/w32api/libcryptext.a
    /lib/w32api/libcryptnet.a
    /lib/w32api/libcryptsp.a
    /lib/w32api/libcryptsvc.a
    /lib/w32api/libcryptui.a
    /lib/w32api/libcryptxml.a
    /usr/lib/w32api/libcrypt32.a
    /usr/lib/w32api/libcryptdlg.a
    /usr/lib/w32api/libcryptdll.a
    /usr/lib/w32api/libcryptext.a
    /usr/lib/w32api/libcryptnet.a
    /usr/lib/w32api/libcryptsp.a
    /usr/lib/w32api/libcryptsvc.a
    /usr/lib/w32api/libcryptui.a
    /usr/lib/w32api/libcryptxml.a
```

**so, symlinking:**

`ln -s /lib/w32api/libcrypt32.a /lib/w32api/libcrypt.a`

**... did the trick. qed.**

Comment: Can anyone please point either to mainainers of `ld` or of `cygwin` or any other relevant maintainer in order to save human's future live-hours. ;)